# How to create a private channel in a Discord server (not a user/bot DM) using JDA: Java Discord API

Tags: discord-jda

I'm trying to get the bot to create a private channel in the guild but can't find anything in the JDA documentation that allows that to happen. The ChannelAction that gets returned when you call `createTextChannel()` has text as the channel type explicitly in the return (`return new ChannelAction(route, name, guild, ChannelType.TEXT);`).

Currently I have it working to just create a text channel with:

`guild.getController().createTextChannel(channelName).complete();`

but I need it to be a private channel. I've experimented a bit with trying to write my own `createPrivateChannel()` method, but it always comes back to needing some implementation of it already in the JDA GuildController.java. I also have looked at the `openPrivateChannel()` but that's for DMs between the user and the bot, and I need a private channel in the server/guild.

Any ideas? Do I just need to go the long route and create the text channel and then mess with the permissions to make it visible to the correct users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a "private" channel by using permission overrides. For this you first need to create that channel using [`createTextChannel(name)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#createTextChannel(java.lang.String)) which will return a [`ChannelAction<TextChannel>`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/restaction/ChannelAction.html).

This interface allows you to do some additional configuration such as permission overrides (we need this). You need to deny the `VIEW_CHANNEL` permission for the public role `@everyone` and allow it for the specific role/member that you want to give access to.

```java
public static void createTextChannel(Member member, String name) {
    Guild guild = member.getGuild();
    guild.createTextChannel(name)
         .addPermissionOverride(member, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL), null)
         .addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL))
         .queue(); // this actually sends the request to discord.
}
```

In JDA 3.X you need to use `guild.getController().createTextChannel()` but that version is no longer supported and you should be using JDA 4.X now. For more information on how to  migrate see [the migration guide](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/0)-Migrating-to-V4).